# Centralizers and algebraic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a linear algebraic group - I am also happy to assume $G$ is a simple algebraic group over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, but the question won't require this.

The centralizer dimension of a group $G$, $dim_c(G)$, (if it exists) is the largest positive integer $n$ such that every strictly descending chain of centralizers in $G$ has length at most $n$.

(Edit: by a chain of centralizers, I mean a chain of subgroups in which every subgroup is the centralizer of some set of elements of the group. Again at this point there are several possible interpretations - I'd be happy to work over $\mathbb C$ and think of points in $G( \mathbb C )$ but more generally, when $k$ is the field of definition, it might be interesting to consider $G(k)$ or $G(k^{alg})$.)

It isn't hard to see that if $H \leq G$ then $dim_c(H) \leq dim_c (G)$. It also isn't hard to see that the centralizer dimension of $GL_n$ is at most $n^2+1$ (basically since centralizers are given by systems of linear equations).

For simple $G$ (or more generally) is there a way to get a better bound on $dim_c(G)$ than using the bound induced by a faithful representation of $G$?

One additional question: supposing that $Z(G) =1$, so that a maximal chain of centralizers will end with $1_G$, is there a technique to calculate the shortest length of a chain of centralizers which ends with $1_G$?

(Again, I am mostly interested in the simple characteristic zero case over an algebraically closed field.)

Comment: What does it mean  a "strictly descending chain of centralizers in $G$" ?

Comment: Would it make sense if I wrote “descending chain of subgroups”? I mean by containment of course. Centralizers are subgroups, and I mean the subgroups in the chain are contained in, but not equal to eachother.

Comment: My question is not what a strictly descending chain is. The question is, what does "a chain of centralizers" mean. Please kindly edit your question and explain your terminology for the benefit of the MO community.

Comment: OK, thanks - my mistake -  I mean that every group in the chain should be a centralizer of some set.

Comment: A centralizer of what kiind of a set? Of a  subset of $G(k)$ where $k$ is the field of definition of $G$? Please edit your question!

Comment: It is usual to say that the length of a chain $G_0<G_1<\dots<G_n$ is $n$ (and not $n+1$) [see for instance the notion of Krull dimension]. Hence the obvious upper bound for $\mathrm{GL}_n$ is $n^2$ (rather than $n^2+1$).

Comment: Note that I've edited the question along the lines requested above.

Comment: I also think it would be natural to call the length of such a chain $n$, but in (the one or two) papers mentioning centralizer dimension which I've seen, they used the terminology in the way I did (unless I'm just confused!). In any case, I do agree with what you write YCor.